# Counting missing values based on a condition

Tags: r

I currently have the following;

```
na_count <- sapply(df, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))
na_count <- data.frame(na_count)
```

Which counts the number of NA values across all columns of a `data.frame`. However I have an additional binary column which I would like to take into consideration also.

For instance:

Count all NA values across all columns which have the value `1` in column `x`.

How can I go about incorporating this into the above function?

Comment: `sum(length(which(is.na(y))))` is the same as `sum(is.na(y))`, which is easier to read.

Comment: `colSums(is.na(df[df$x==1,]))` should give the desired result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest modification is just subsetting the dataframe, as such:

```
na_count <-sapply(df[df$x==1,], function(y) sum(is.na(y)))
```